# How to change global navigation bar title with delegates?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, textfield

I need to write something in a textField and when a press return in the keyboard change the global title in my navigation bar (for the entire app).

I've been asked to perform this action with delegates but I don't find any delegate method from navigationController to perform this.

Comment: You're going to have to set each view controller's title in their viewDidLoad or equivalent

Comment: I need to perform it with navBar delegates

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can acheive but you have to handle in each pushing / presenting View controller. The best way would be subclassing navigation controller and override the title while pushing / presenting view controller.

**Custom Nav Controller:** 
[image]

**Swift Code:**

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    var navFixedTitle: String?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.title = navFixedTitle ?? "Constant"
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }

    //Nav Bar Delegate
    func navigationBar(navigationBar: UINavigationBar, didPushItem item: UINavigationItem) {
//        navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Back"
    }
}
```

**Set your title:**

I've used Table View, when tapping on different cell the nav title will set accordingly.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let nav = self.navigationController as? MyNavigationController {
        nav.navFixedTitle = sec1[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
}
```

**Output:**

[image]